# how to solve git log message with messy code

Tags: git

Recently, I found that on my one linux machine, all my git log message end with strange code, like this: (U <yuA  shouldn't be here!) while other machine and remote repo is Okay!

```
commit 
Author: 
Date:   Mon Aug 5 18:10:29 2019 +0800

    init
    U <yuA
```

and my soft links were also strange:

```
 libnames.so -> libnames.so.1Uo
```

actually should be libnames.so.1 ;

Do Anyone know why is this and how to resolve?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i do curious with your case. is this repository newly cloned?

Comment: thanks~. yeah, new cloned repo will meet this question; while old repo git checkout new file also meet :(

Comment: It's very hard to be sure based on what you've said here, but my guess is that you have your machine set up such that whatever Git is running as its pager (`core.pager`, `GIT_PAGER`, etc)., this pager is adding this strange text you're seeing. You can use `git var GIT_PAGER` to find out which pager program you've chosen. Then, check to see if this pager program is working correctly.

Comment: @torek thanks, I checked my GIT_PAGER, it's `pager`, but it seems ok; when I tried to change it to `less`, the strange code is still there.....

Comment: Try running `git --no-pager show` or similar to see if that makes the strange characters vanish. If so, it's still something to do with the pager; if not, it's not. You can also run `pager` and/or `less` on files with known good content to see if that shows the same symptoms. If it's not the pager, I'm not sure what to try next, though I'd ask how you *connect to* the machine where you see these issues: maybe the problem is in the connectivity software.

Comment: `git --no-pager show` still make strange chars; but they are different from `less` or `pager`; for exam:```less: Date:   Fri Aug 23 15:33:35 2019 +0800

    update lib
    U<F9>&<F5>^?
``` while no-pager shows ```Date:   Fri Aug 23 15:33:35 2019 +0800

    update lib
    U�͐
``` and I connect the machine through ssh, on my mac Iterm2 and terminal both tried